# Linear Probing - Delete Function Not Working Properly

Tags: c++, hashtable, linear-probing

Here's a snippet of a Linear Probing program that I'm working on. I'm focusing on the `insertElement` and `deleteElement` functions:

```cpp
class HashMapTable
{
    // initializing the size of the hash table
    int table_size;

    // a pointer* vector that points to an array on the hash table containing the keys
    vector<int>* table;

public:
    // creating a parameterized constructor of the above class containing all the methods
    HashMapTable(int key);

    // hash function formula to compute the index using table_size and key
    int hashFunction(int key) {
        return (key % table_size);
    }

    // inserting a key in the hash table
    void insertElement(int key);

    // deleting a key in the hash table
    void deleteElement(int key);
```

```cpp
void HashMapTable::insertElement(int key)
{
    int index = hashFunction(key); // index of array equating to the key%table_size

    if (table[index].empty()) {
        table[index].push_back(key);
    }
    else {
        do {
            index = (index + 1) % table_size;   // temp_key % table_size
        } while (!table[index].empty());
        table[index].push_back(key);
        
        cout << table[index].at(0) << " has been shifted by " << index << " iteration(s)" << endl;
    }

void HashMapTable::deleteElement(int key)
{
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    
    auto i = find(table[index].begin(), table[index].end(), key);
    if (i != table[index].end())
        table[index].erase(i);  

    cout << key << "'s true index is found at " << index << ". ";
    cout << key << " modulo " << table_size << " is " << key % table_size << "\n\n";
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    // array of all the keys to be inserted in the hash table
    int arr[] = { 20, 34, 56, 54, 76, 87 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    // table_size of hash table as 6
    HashMapTable ht(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        ht.insertElement(arr[i]);

    // deleting a key from the hash table
    ht.deleteElement(87);

    // displaying the final data of hash table
    ht.displayHashTable();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
56 has been shifted by 3 iteration(s)
76 has been shifted by 5 iteration(s)
87 has been shifted by 1 iteration(s)
87's true index is found at 3. 87 modulo 6 is 3

0 ==> 54
1 ==> 87
2 ==> 20
3 ==> 56
4 ==> 34
5 ==> 76
```

I'm attempting to delete element `87` from the vector, but the `deleteElement` function seems to reading the initial modulo of each element and attempting to delete them from their initial positions, even though the `insertElement` already shifted them to an empty slot. I'm very confused as to why this is happening.

Comment: If you check [**here**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing#Deletion) for what may be necessary when deleting a cell from a hash table structure using linear probing, I think you'll find the description as informative, as its implementation is completely lacking, from your source code. After your table erase you *may* still have work left to do to plug the hole you just created.

Comment: This looks like chaining and not linear probing 

auto i = find(table[index].begin(), table[index].end(), key);

Comment: Where is storage for `table` defined? Where is the `std::vector<int>`? Global? Where is the constructor defined? Providing a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question. While I get there is a vector somewhere, you hash and check the index, the loop and increment until you find an empty one, what isn't clear is how you handle existing keys that hash to an index they may be in your way, or determine which index a key goes to then.

Comment: In other words where is the 3-iterations in `56 has been shifted by 3 iteration(s)` stored? Or do find/remove `56` is the approach just to hash `56` and iterate indexes until you find it? Then what happens if a key that hashes between the original hash and where `56` lives is removed before needing to remove `56`? In that case the linear iteration breaks before `56` is found. Traversing the whole table in `deleteElement()` seems completely counter-productive to the efficiency of the map. The MRE would really help.